# waitForCondition class change

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I'm having an issue with a menu which needs a double click to activate the main option.

The first click adds 'focus open' classes to get the UI to open the hover over menu in mobile, the second activates it as a link.

I want to use the waitForCondition command to wait until the menu is open and then click the link again.

Although a more efficient option might be to do a double click but this doesn't seem to work so far.